# How to draw Line chart in monoandroid(xamarin) with shinobi chart library

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, shinobi

I am using "shinobicontrols" (link given bellow) for my mono android application(xamarin).so, now i want to draw line chart for two data field one for "ask" price and one for "bid" price.  so, any one can help me? 
thanks in advance ....

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/android/shinobicharts/price-plans

Comment: do you have tried? than show your code

Comment: sorry i not tried because i don't know about which series i have to use for bind data in chart.thanks for quick reply

Comment: its paid Lib for chart right ? and its compulsory to use this ??

Comment: yes, you are right ..

Comment: ok i don't have any idea about this lib :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to ask for help relating to Shinobi Charts is their forums, there you will get help from people who are familiar with the libraries and the devs themselves.

It seems like you are just getting started, so the best place to begin would be the user guide, available here:
http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiChartsAndroid/1.3.5/Premium/Normal/user-guide/index.html

This will take you through the steps needed to create and render a chart, there are also more detailed API documentation for the Xamarin bindings, for example for a Line Series (which is what it sounds like you are wanting to use):
http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiChartsAndroid/1.3.5/Premium/MonoTouch/Com.ShinobiControls.Charts/LineSeries.html

Finally if you are still having problems feel free to post on the forums:
http://www.shinobicontrols.com/forum/shinobicontrols

Hope this helps, if you are still struggling just let us know what we can do to help.

Craig.

(Full disclosure: I work for ShinobiControls)